# bijection between points and algebra homomorphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

if we consider $\psi:V\to Hom(\mathbb{F}[V],\mathbb{F})$ such that $a\mapsto ev_a$. Is this map a bijection when $\mathbb{F}$ is algebraically closed?**

Answer (score 0):

> But is this map the unique F-algebra homomorphism with this kernel?

Yes. If you have another map $\mathbb{F}[V] \rightarrow A$ with the same kernel, there exists a unique isomorphism between the images, commuting with the maps. This is a corollary of the homomorphism theorem for rings.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please give me a reference so that I can found the result you stated?

Comment: Every beginners book on abstract algebra should have it, you may also consult Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_on_homomorphisms

Answer (score 0):

The maps will be the same up to isomorphism.

For your second question, remember: for a$\in$ V to be in the kernel, f(a)=0 in $\mathbb{F}[V]$,**the quotient ring**.

Comment: ah! Thanks! I was being stupid!   Could you please tell me how to show the uniqueness? thanks

Comment: This is just a consequence of the First Homomorphism Theorem. So you have two homomorphisms f:X$\rightarrow$Y and g:X$\rightarrow$Z both with the same kernel K. What can be said about X/K?

Comment: $X/K$ must be isomorphic to both the image of $f$ and $g$. so it means $image(f)\cong image(g)$. what can I deduce from here? thanks

Comment: You're done. If the images are isomorphic, and the domains are the same, then the homomorphisms are essentially the same. We will have f = $\phi \circ g$ where $\phi$ is the isomorphism. There is not a unique map per se. It is unique up to isomorphism.

Comment: oh I see... I was thinking every map should be precisely the same as $ev_a$. silly me. Many thanks!

Comment: @JoelPereira why $f(a)$ is in $\mathbb{F}(V)$? it should be in  $\mathbb{F}$, is it? or you mean $\psi(a)$ and it should be a zero map in the hom space?

Comment: @Tortuga.A you're right. I should have written $\psi(a)$ = $ev_a$=0.